# Apply a jquery plugin to a second Select when it apears

Tags: jquery

I have a page that shows a Select with main categories and when you select one option a second Select appears (with subcategories).

The problem is that this second Select is not converted by the jquery plugin because it is loaded only after i click on a option from first Select (and when the page is fully loaded). 
So, any idea how to make it apply to second Select? Can it be done?

I did not placed a second Select because i do not know how to make it load only when i click on a option from first Select.

Both Select come dynamic from php file and you can see them live on https://demo.osclass.org/general/index.php?page=item&action=item_add

```js
/*
 * jQuery Selectbox plugin 0.2
 *
 * Copyright 2011-2012, Dimitar Ivanov (http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/)
 * Licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) license.
 *
 * Date: Tue Jul 17 19:58:36 2012 +0300
 */
(function($, undefined) {
  var PROP_NAME = "selectbox",
    FALSE = false,
    TRUE = true;

  function Selectbox() {
    this._state = [];
    this._defaults = {
      classHolder: "sbHolder",
      classHolderDisabled: "sbHolderDisabled",
      classSelector: "sbSelector",
      classOptions: "sbOptions",
      classGroup: "sbGroup",
      classSub: "sbSub",
      classDisabled: "sbDisabled",
      classToggleOpen: "sbToggleOpen",
      classToggle: "sbToggle",
      classFocus: "sbFocus",
      speed: 200,
      effect: "slide",
      onChange: null,
      onOpen: null,
      onClose: null
    }
  }
  $.extend(Selectbox.prototype, {
    _isOpenSelectbox: function(target) {
      if (!target) {
        return FALSE
      }
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      return inst.isOpen
    },
    _isDisabledSelectbox: function(target) {
      if (!target) {
        return FALSE
      }
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      return inst.isDisabled
    },
    _attachSelectbox: function(target, settings) {
      if (this._getInst(target)) {
        return FALSE
      }
      var $target = $(target),
        self = this,
        inst = self._newInst($target),
        sbHolder, sbSelector, sbToggle, sbOptions, s = FALSE,
        optGroup = $target.find("optgroup"),
        opts = $target.find("option"),
        olen = opts.length;
      $target.attr("sb", inst.uid);
      $.extend(inst.settings, self._defaults, settings);
      self._state[inst.uid] = FALSE;
      $target.hide();

      function closeOthers() {
        var key, sel, uid = this.attr("id").split("_")[1];
        for (key in self._state) {
          if (key !== uid) {
            if (self._state.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              sel = $("select[sb='" + key + "']")[0];
              if (sel) {
                self._closeSelectbox(sel)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      sbHolder = $("<div>", {
        id: "sbHolder_" + inst.uid,
        "class": inst.settings.classHolder,
        tabindex: $target.attr("tabindex")
      });
      sbSelector = $("<a>", {
        id: "sbSelector_" + inst.uid,
        href: "#",
        "class": inst.settings.classSelector,
        click: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          closeOthers.apply($(this), []);
          var uid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
          if (self._state[uid]) {
            self._closeSelectbox(target)
          } else {
            self._openSelectbox(target)
          }
        }
      });
      sbToggle = $("<a>", {
        id: "sbToggle_" + inst.uid,
        href: "#",
        "class": inst.settings.classToggle,
        click: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          closeOthers.apply($(this), []);
          var uid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
          if (self._state[uid]) {
            self._closeSelectbox(target)
          } else {
            self._openSelectbox(target)
          }
        }
      });
      sbToggle.appendTo(sbHolder);
      sbOptions = $("<ul>", {
        id: "sbOptions_" + inst.uid,
        "class": inst.settings.classOptions,
        css: {
          display: "none"
        }
      });
      $target.children().each(function(i) {
        var that = $(this),
          li, config = {};
        if (that.is("option")) {
          getOptions(that)
        } else {
          if (that.is("optgroup")) {
            li = $("<li>");
            $("<span>", {
              text: that.attr("label")
            }).addClass(inst.settings.classGroup).appendTo(li);
            li.appendTo(sbOptions);
            if (that.is(":disabled")) {
              config.disabled = true
            }
            config.sub = true;
            getOptions(that.find("option"), config)
          }
        }
      });

      function getOptions() {
        var sub = arguments[1] && arguments[1].sub ? true : false,
          disabled = arguments[1] && arguments[1].disabled ? true : false;
        arguments[0].each(function(i) {
          var that = $(this),
            li = $("<li>"),
            child;
          if (that.is(":selected")) {
            sbSelector.text(that.text());
            s = TRUE
          }
          if (i === olen - 1) {
            li.addClass("last")
          }
          if (!that.is(":disabled") && !disabled) {
            child = $("<a>", {
              href: "#" + that.val(),
              rel: that.val()
            }).text(that.text()).bind("click.sb", function(e) {
              if (e && e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault()
              }
              var t = sbToggle,
                $this = $(this),
                uid = t.attr("id").split("_")[1];
              self._changeSelectbox(target, $this.attr("rel"), $this.text());
              self._closeSelectbox(target)
            }).bind("mouseover.sb", function() {
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
              $this.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus)
            }).bind("mouseout.sb", function() {
              $(this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus)
            });
            if (sub) {
              child.addClass(inst.settings.classSub)
            }
            if (that.is(":selected")) {
              child.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus)
            }
            child.appendTo(li)
          } else {
            child = $("<span>", {
              text: that.text()
            }).addClass(inst.settings.classDisabled);
            if (sub) {
              child.addClass(inst.settings.classSub)
            }
            child.appendTo(li)
          }
          li.appendTo(sbOptions)
        })
      }
      if (!s) {
        sbSelector.text(opts.first().text())
      }
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst);
      sbHolder.data("uid", inst.uid).bind("keydown.sb", function(e) {
        var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0,
          $this = $(this),
          uid = $this.data("uid"),
          inst = $this.siblings("select[sb='" + uid + "']").data(PROP_NAME),
          trgt = $this.siblings(["select[sb='", uid, "']"].join("")).get(0),
          $f = $this.find("ul").find("a." + inst.settings.classFocus);
        switch (key) {
          case 37:
          case 38:
            if ($f.length > 0) {
              var $next;
              $("a", $this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
              $next = $f.parent().prevAll("li:has(a)").eq(0).find("a");
              if ($next.length > 0) {
                $next.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus).focus();
                $("#sbSelector_" + uid).text($next.text())
              }
            }
            break;
          case 39:
          case 40:
            var $next;
            $("a", $this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus);
            if ($f.length > 0) {
              $next = $f.parent().nextAll("li:has(a)").eq(0).find("a")
            } else {
              $next = $this.find("ul").find("a").eq(0)
            } if ($next.length > 0) {
              $next.addClass(inst.settings.classFocus).focus();
              $("#sbSelector_" + uid).text($next.text())
            }
            break;
          case 13:
            if ($f.length > 0) {
              self._changeSelectbox(trgt, $f.attr("rel"), $f.text())
            }
            self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
            break;
          case 9:
            if (trgt) {
              var inst = self._getInst(trgt);
              if (inst) {
                if ($f.length > 0) {
                  self._changeSelectbox(trgt, $f.attr("rel"), $f.text())
                }
                self._closeSelectbox(trgt)
              }
            }
            var i = parseInt($this.attr("tabindex"), 10);
            if (!e.shiftKey) {
              i++
            } else {
              i--
            }
            $("*[tabindex='" + i + "']").focus();
            break;
          case 27:
            self._closeSelectbox(trgt);
            break
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false
      }).delegate("a", "mouseover", function(e) {
        $(this).addClass(inst.settings.classFocus)
      }).delegate("a", "mouseout", function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass(inst.settings.classFocus)
      });
      sbSelector.appendTo(sbHolder);
      sbOptions.appendTo(sbHolder);
      sbHolder.insertAfter($target);
      $("html").live("mousedown", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("select").selectbox("close")
      });
      $([".", inst.settings.classHolder, ", .", inst.settings.classSelector].join("")).mousedown(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
      })
    },
    _detachSelectbox: function(target) {
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (!inst) {
        return FALSE
      }
      $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).remove();
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, null);
      $(target).show()
    },
    _changeSelectbox: function(target, value, text) {
      var onChange, inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (inst) {
        onChange = this._get(inst, "onChange");
        $("#sbSelector_" + inst.uid).text(text)
      }
      value = value.replace(/\'/g, "\\'");
      $(target).find("option[value='" + value + "']").attr("selected", TRUE);
      if (inst && onChange) {
        onChange.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [value, inst])
      } else {
        if (inst && inst.input) {
          inst.input.trigger("change")
        }
      }
    },
    _enableSelectbox: function(target) {
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (!inst || !inst.isDisabled) {
        return FALSE
      }
      $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).removeClass(inst.settings.classHolderDisabled);
      inst.isDisabled = FALSE;
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst)
    },
    _disableSelectbox: function(target) {
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (!inst || inst.isDisabled) {
        return FALSE
      }
      $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).addClass(inst.settings.classHolderDisabled);
      inst.isDisabled = TRUE;
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst)
    },
    _optionSelectbox: function(target, name, value) {
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (!inst) {
        return FALSE
      }
      inst[name] = value;
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst)
    },
    _openSelectbox: function(target) {
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (!inst || inst.isOpen || inst.isDisabled) {
        return
      }
      var el = $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid),
        viewportHeight = parseInt($(window).height(), 10),
        offset = $("#sbHolder_" + inst.uid).offset(),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        height = el.prev().height(),
        diff = viewportHeight - (offset.top - scrollTop) - height / 2,
        onOpen = this._get(inst, "onOpen");
      el.css({
        top: height + "px",
        maxHeight: (diff - height) + "px"
      });
      inst.settings.effect === "fade" ? el.fadeIn(inst.settings.speed) : el.slideDown(inst.settings.speed);
      $("#sbToggle_" + inst.uid).addClass(inst.settings.classToggleOpen);
      this._state[inst.uid] = TRUE;
      inst.isOpen = TRUE;
      if (onOpen) {
        onOpen.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst])
      }
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst)
    },
    _closeSelectbox: function(target) {
      var inst = this._getInst(target);
      if (!inst || !inst.isOpen) {
        return
      }
      var onClose = this._get(inst, "onClose");
      inst.settings.effect === "fade" ? $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid).fadeOut(inst.settings.speed) : $("#sbOptions_" + inst.uid).slideUp(inst.settings.speed);
      $("#sbToggle_" + inst.uid).removeClass(inst.settings.classToggleOpen);
      this._state[inst.uid] = FALSE;
      inst.isOpen = FALSE;
      if (onClose) {
        onClose.apply((inst.input ? inst.input[0] : null), [inst])
      }
      $.data(target, PROP_NAME, inst)
    },
    _newInst: function(target) {
      var id = target[0].id.replace(/([^A-Za-z0-9_-])/g, "\\\\$1");
      return {
        id: id,
        input: target,
        uid: Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999999),
        isOpen: FALSE,
        isDisabled: FALSE,
        settings: {}
      }
    },
    _getInst: function(target) {
      try {
        return $.data(target, PROP_NAME)
      } catch (err) {
        throw "Missing instance data for this selectbox"
      }
    },
    _get: function(inst, name) {
      return inst.settings[name] !== undefined ? inst.settings[name] : this._defaults[name]
    }
  });
  $.fn.selectbox = function(options) {
    var otherArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    if (typeof options == "string" && options == "isDisabled") {
      return $.selectbox["_" + options + "Selectbox"].apply($.selectbox, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs))
    }
    if (options == "option" && arguments.length == 2 && typeof arguments[1] == "string") {
      return $.selectbox["_" + options + "Selectbox"].apply($.selectbox, [this[0]].concat(otherArgs))
    }
    return this.each(function() {
      typeof options == "string" ? $.selectbox["_" + options + "Selectbox"].apply($.selectbox, [this].concat(otherArgs)) : $.selectbox._attachSelectbox(this, options)
    })
  };
  $.selectbox = new Selectbox();
  $.selectbox.version = "0.2"
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").selectbox({
    effect: "fade"
});
$("#select_2").selectbox({
    effect: "fade"
});
});
```

```css
.sbHolder {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  border: solid 1px #515151;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.sbHolder:focus .sbSelector {} .sbSelector {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 10px;
  top: 0;
  width: 170px;
}
.sbSelector:link,
.sbSelector:visited,
.sbSelector:hover {
  color: #EBB52D;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sbToggle {
  background: url(../img/select-icons.png) 0 -116px no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
}
.sbToggle:hover {
  background: url(../img/select-icons.png) 0 -167px no-repeat;
}
.sbToggleOpen {
  background: url(../img/select-icons.png) 0 -16px no-repeat;
}
.sbToggleOpen:hover {
  background: url(../img/select-icons.png) 0 -66px no-repeat;
}
.sbHolderDisabled {
  background-color: #3C3C3C;
  border: solid 1px #515151;
}
.sbHolderDisabled .sbHolder {} .sbHolderDisabled .sbToggle {} .sbOptions {
  background-color: #212121;
  border: solid 1px #515151;
  list-style: none;
  left: -1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.sbOptions li {
  padding: 0 7px;
}
.sbOptions a {
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #515151;
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 3px;
}
.sbOptions a:link,
.sbOptions a:visited {
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sbOptions a:hover,
.sbOptions a:focus,
.sbOptions a.sbFocus {
  color: #EBB52D;
}
.sbOptions li.last a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.sbOptions .sbDisabled {
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #515151;
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 3px;
}
.sbOptions .sbGroup {
  border-bottom: dotted 1px #515151;
  color: #EBB52D;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 0 7px 3px;
}
.sbOptions .sbSub {
  padding-left: 17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1">
  <option value="0">Select category</option>
  <option value="109">Category 1</option>
  <option value="118">Category 2</option>
  <option value="121">Category 3</option>
  <option value="122">Category 4</option>
  <option value="123">Category 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if i use $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', '#select_2', function () {
    $(this).selectbox();
}); the second select will show properly but on click the subcategories are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you apply the plugin to the first `select`:

```
$("select").selectbox({
    effect: "fade"
});
```

You would simply need to execute this plugin initialization again **after the second `select` is created**.

Note that if the plugin initialization in any way resets the first `select` or for whatever reason an element can't/shouldn't be initialized with the plugin more than once, then you would want to more specifically identify the target element(s) in the jQuery selector.  So, for example, if the second `select` has a specific `id` then you can target that:

```
$("#theSecondSelectID").selectbox({
    effect: "fade"
});
```

Comment: Hello David. Adding a second $("#select_2").selectbox({
    effect: "fade"
}); has no effect. The subcategory Select doesn't have the jquery style

Comment: @Adyyda: Does that `id` match the element?  Does the element exist when this code executes?  When you debug this, does that jQuery selector find any element?

Comment: Yes, that the id - with firebug i see the second select as <select id="select_2" class="valid" depth="2" name="select_2">. I see no errors in debug. This situation happened with 2 others jquery plugins for select. All 3 of them works perfect when i have a simple select with normal options or with optgroup and will not work when a second select apears after i make a selection in first one.

Comment: @Adyyda: Can you update the code in the question to show what you've changed?  You're not really answering the debugging questions, I'd need to see the actual code to know more.

Comment: @Adyyda: Regarding your updated code, that second plugin initialization happens *immediately* when the page loads.  However, the problem you're describing is that the element **doesn't exist** until some later time.  (It's dynamically created in response to user input.)  You can't initialize a plugin on an element that doesn't yet exist.  The plugin initialization for the second `select` needs to happen *after* that `select` is added to the page.

Comment: Yes, i suspected that but i don't know how to do it - The plugin initialization for the second select needs to happen after that select is added to the page.

Comment: @Adyyda: Well, where in your code is the second `select` element added to the page?  You'd simply perform this action immediately after that.  You've shared *a lot* of code here.  Somewhere in all of your code is where you add the element to the page, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94947/discussion-between-adyyda-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

You can create and fire selectbox for second select element on "onChange" function. Is it what you are searching for?

```
$("select").selectbox({
    effect: "fade",
    onChange: function(e){
        var sbVal = $("#secondSelect").attr("sb");
        $("#sbHolder_" + sbVal).remove();
        $("#secondSelect").remove();

        $("body").append("<select id='secondSelect' />");
        $("#secondSelect").append("<option>"+e+"</option>");
        $("#secondSelect").selectbox({
            effect: "fade"
        });
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rs9boo6L/3/

Comment: This looks interesting but why does the second select return the value="x"> of option selected in first select? When i select Category 1 for instance, i should see like Subcategory 1, Subcategory 2, Subcategory 3, Subcategory 4

Comment: Because I had no sucategories. :) I updates the example with binding 10 subcategories. https://jsfiddle.net/rs9boo6L/3/

Comment: Your update did not save properly. It looks the same.

Comment: Actually it looks ok to me. I bound 10 subcategories with selected category id on their name? I provided a link in comment.